# how to make webview in vue-native

Tags: vue-native

i am trying to make webview application with vue-native-cli

i am trying to use web-view component with help of [documents](https://vue-native.io/docs/basic-components.html#WebView)

this is my page

```
<template>
    <web-view
        :source="'https://google.com'"
        :style="{marginTop: 20}"
    />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {

  }
}
</script>
<style>

</style>
```

when i use

```
<view class="text-container">
        <text>Hello World</text>
    </view>
```

its working fine but in webview getting

invarian voilation: Element type is invalid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that some pieces of React Native have changed under the hood and the Vue Native docs haven't yet been updated to address it. Answer as of March 2020:

1. Install the webview component via `expo install react-native-webview`
2. Import into your component
3. Make sure your `:source` prop passes the uri as an object:

```
<template>
    <web-view :source="{uri:'https://google.com'}" />
</template>

<script>
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

export default {
  name: "myComponent",
  components: {
    "web-view": WebView
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: How about we have to add originWhitelist:{["*"]} as well??



`<web-view
    originWhitelist:{["*"]}
    source={{
    html: View,
    }}`

Answer (score 0):

you have to import WebView first

```
import { WebView } from "react-native";
export default {
    components: {
      'web-view': WebView
    },
};

<template>
    <web-view
        :source="'https://google.com'"
        :style="{marginTop: 20}"
    />
</template>
```